# RabbitMQ - Scheduled Queue - Dead Letter Queue - Good practise

Tags: rabbitmq, bunny

we have setup some workflow environment with Rabbit.

It solves our needs but I like to know if it is also good practise to do it like we do for scheduled tasks.

Scheduling means no mission critical 100% adjusted time. So if a job should be retried after 60 seconds, it does mean 60+ seconds, depends on when the queue is handled.

I have created one Q_WAIT and made some headers to transport settings.

Lets do it like:

Worker is running subscribed on Q_ACTION

If the action missed (e.g. smtp server not reachable)

-> (Re-)Publish the message to Q_WAIT and set properties.headers["scheduled"] = time + 60seconds

---

Another process **loops** every 15 seconds through all messages in Q_WAIT by method pop() and NOT by subscribed

```
q_WAIT.pop(:ack => true) do |delivery_info,properties,body|...

  if (properties.headers["scheduled"] has reached its time)

     -> (Re-)Publish the message back to Q_ACTION
        ack(message)
```

---

after each loop, the connection is closed so that the NOT (Re-)Published are left in Q_WAIT because they were not acknowledged.

---

Can someone confirm this as a working (good) practise.

Comment: Why not just utilize per-queue or per-message ttl from [Time-To-Live Extensions](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can use looping process like described in original question.

Also, you can utilize [Time-To-Live Extension](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html) with [Dead Letter Exchanges extension](http://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html).

First, specify `x-dead-letter-exchange` `Q_WAIT` queue argument equal to current exchange and `x-dead-letter-routing-key` equal to routing key that `Q_ACTION` bound.

Then set `x-message-ttl` queue argument set or set message expires property during publishing if you need custom per-message ttl (which is not best practice though while there are some [well-known caveats](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#per-message-ttl-caveats), but it works too).

In this case your messages will be dead-lettered from `Q_WAIT` to `Q_ACTION` right after their ttl expires without any additional consumers, which is more reliable and stable.

Note, if you need advanced re-publish logic (change message body, properties) you need additional queue (say `Q_PRE_ACTION`) to consume messages from, change them and then publish to target queue (say `Q_ACTION`).

Comment: In case of short comments, I have posted my remarks to another answer. Could you please have a look on, maybe I have some missunderstanding.

Comment: Yeah, it's ok, you implement exactly what I mentioned.

Comment: Have you got also question about per-message-ttl? It seems that the Dead-Letter-Queue will ignore any message specific ttl even if it is shorter then queue-ttl. Do you know something about this?

Comment: There are no any Dead Letter Queues in RabbitMQ, only Dead Letter Exchanges. And after message was dead-lettered it `expires` property will be stored to `original-expiration` header.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here in comments I tried that feature of `x-dead-letter-exchange` and it worked for most requirements. One question / missunderstandig is TTL-PER-MESSAGE option.

Please look on the example here. From my understanding:

1. the DLQ has a timeout of 10 seconds
2. so first message will be available on subscriber 10 seconds after publishing.
3. the second message is posted 1 second after the first with a message-ttl (expiration) of 3 seconds

I would expect the second message should be prounounced after 3 seconds from publishing and before first message.

But it did not work like that, both are available after 10 seconds.

**Q: Shouldn't the message expiration overrule the DLQ ttl?**

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8

require 'bunny'

B = Bunny.new ENV['CLOUDAMQP_URL']
B.start

DELAYED_QUEUE='work.later'
DESTINATION_QUEUE='work.now'

def publish
  ch = B.create_channel
  # declare a queue with the DELAYED_QUEUE name
  q = ch.queue(DELAYED_QUEUE, :durable => true, arguments: {
    # set the dead-letter exchange to the default queue
    'x-dead-letter-exchange' => '',
    # when the message expires, set change the routing key into the destination queue name
    'x-dead-letter-routing-key' => DESTINATION_QUEUE,
    # the time in milliseconds to keep the message in the queue
    'x-message-ttl' => 10000,
  })
  # publish to the default exchange with the the delayed queue name as routing key,
  # so that the message ends up in the newly declared delayed queue
  ch.basic_publish('message content 1 ' + Time.now.strftime("%H-%M-%S"), "", DELAYED_QUEUE, :persistent => true)
  puts "#{Time.now}: Published the message 1"

  # wait moment before next publish
  sleep 1.0

  # puts this with a shorter ttl
  ch.basic_publish('message content 2 ' + Time.now.strftime("%H-%M-%S"), "", DELAYED_QUEUE, :persistent => true, :expiration => "3000")
  puts "#{Time.now}: Published the message 2"

  ch.close
end

def subscribe
  ch = B.create_channel
  # declare the destination queue
  q = ch.queue DESTINATION_QUEUE, durable: true 
  q.subscribe do |delivery, headers, body|
    puts "#{Time.now}: Got the message: #{body}"
  end
end

subscribe()
publish()

sleep
```

Comment: From [RabbitMQ TTL Extension manual](www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#per-message-ttl): When both a per-queue and a per-message TTL are specified, the lower value between the two will be chosen. Maybe, you should refer to rubybunny manual - http://rubybunny.info/articles/extensions.html#permessage_timetolive (while I'm not sure about whether `expiration` should be passed as string number or as plain number, internally in AMQP `expiration` field has string type, but various extensions works different).

Comment: To be sure, try to send two messages manually via management plugin web interface - one with `expiration` property set, and the other without. On my RabbitMQ 3.3.1 server it works as expected, and lower expition time is used when both per-queue and per-message ttl set.

Comment: This spooky ... I checked it as you mentioned and YES it works for me too. No difference if I send message by mgmt web or bunny.

Comment: **BUT** if there is already a message send with a higher or no TTL all messages have to wait: Please test: 

1. Publish message 1 - expiration=10000
1. Publish message 2 - expiration=5000

Both message are delivered after 10000ms

If you do it otherwise

First message after 5000ms second after 100000ms

This behavior is also same for the default TTL.

**Is this a bug or a feature of RabbitMQ?**

Comment: Ah yeah, it is normal (that is why I wrote that per-message ttl is not a best practice at all and should be used only with caveats knowledge). Read [Caveats section of Time-To-Live Extensions](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#per-message-ttl-caveats) doc. It is standard RabbitMQ behavior (while it is not intuitive to understand at first glance, it is very logical and do not violation FIFO idea of RabbitMQ queues).

Comment: Well understand that in case of FIFO. So then my question again went back to original question but more precised: If I am not able to schedule all messages via dead-letter-exchange (good for to forward / schedule actions at a given fix period of time like 60secs) may I use then a looping process like described in the entrance question? There will be just a small number of messages in - lets imagine 25 per day. The loop process will not run more often then every minute or even every 5 minutes. No precisely scheduling nessecary.

Comment: Sure you can. Even under high message flow it will work.